# Cannot resolve method 'activateFetched' in 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

How can I solve this issue? I am setting up my app for Firebase auto update, I got an already built Android studio project that has the complete code which I copied to my app.

The already built project, the Firebase Update (Remote Config) was very fine and I am able to build the apk without issues.

But when I copied the code and the dependency to my app I get error while building the App the `ForeceUpgradeManger.java` shows two line with error

`Cannot resolve method 'setDefaults' in 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'`
`Cannot resolve method 'activateFetched' in 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'`

below is the full code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver;
import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ForceUpgradeManager implements LifecycleObserver {

  private static final String KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED = "force_update_required";
  private static final String KEY_CURRENT_VERSION = "force_update_current_version";

  private static final String TAG = "ForceUpgradeManager";

  private final Context context;

  @Nullable
  private WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakReference;

  public ForceUpgradeManager(ForceUpdateApp application) {
    this.context = application.getApplicationContext();
    application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(callbacks);
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
  }

  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
  public void appStarted() {
    checkForceUpdateNeeded();
  }

  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
  public void appStopped() {
    if (activityWeakReference != null) {
      activityWeakReference.clear();
    }
  }

  @Nullable
  private Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    return activityWeakReference != null && activityWeakReference.get() != null
        ? activityWeakReference.get() : null;
  }

  private final Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callbacks =
      new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
          ForceUpgradeManager.this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity,
            @NonNull Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {

        }
      };

  /**
   * Gets update alert.
   */
  private void onUpdateNeeded() {
    Activity temp = getCurrentActivity();
    if (temp != null) {
      AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(temp)
          .setTitle("New version available")
          .setMessage("Please update app for seamless experience.")
          .setPositiveButton("Continue",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  redirectStore();
                }
              }).create();
      dialog.show();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Redirect to play store
   */
  private void redirectStore() {
    Uri updateUrl = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, updateUrl);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
  }

  private void checkForceUpdateNeeded() {
    final FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    // long cacheExpiration = 12 * 60 * 60; // fetch every 12 hours
    // set in-app defaults
    Map<String, Object> remoteConfigDefaults = new HashMap();
    remoteConfigDefaults.put(KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED, false);
    remoteConfigDefaults.put(KEY_CURRENT_VERSION, "1.0.0");

    remoteConfig.setDefaults(remoteConfigDefaults);
    remoteConfig.fetch(0)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
              Log.d(TAG, "remote config is fetched.");
              remoteConfig.activateFetched();
            }
            if (remoteConfig.getBoolean(KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED)) {
              String currentVersion = remoteConfig.getString(KEY_CURRENT_VERSION);
              String appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
              if (!TextUtils.equals(currentVersion, appVersion)) {
                onUpdateNeeded();
              }
            }
          }
        });
  }

  private String getAppVersion(Context context) {
    String result = "";
    try {
      result = context.getPackageManager()
          .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0)
          .versionName;
      result = result.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]|-", "");
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant method is nowadays called `activate()`. See the documentation for Firebase's [`RemoteConfig` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#activate()) and the release notes for [Android SDK version 20.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#remote-config_v20-0-0) where this change was made:

> Removed the deprecated synchronous method `FirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched()`. Use the asynchronous `FirebaseRemoteConfig.activate()` instead.

So:

```
remoteConfig.activate();
```

Comment: Thanks, quite helpful.